# gcc linker error: version node not found for symbol 

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I'm trying to build a shared library, and I get the following error:

> libavformat.so: version node not found
>   for symbol
>   av_dup_packet@LIBAVFORMAT_52
>
> ld:
>   failed to set dynamic section sizes:
>   Bad value

Does anybody knows what this error means? Host is i586-linux target is arm-linux

**Edit:** Resolved, see comments

Comment: Please post the parameters of gcc that you use for both compiling and linking.

Comment: I got rid of the error - it was specific to the library, caused by a inlined assemby.symver directive

Comment: you could post the solution here as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by an inline assembly directive `.symver`. My solution was to manually modify the generated config.h to disable version nodes symbols.

Check out [internal.h](http://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/internal.h;hb=33586ee770edaa036c27508b5ec5c8c263973941) lines 214-223

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when building [libsctp](http://lksctp.sourceforge.net/) into a custom build environment.

Symbol Versioning is explained [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html) and a linker script may be used to control it.  In my case I was able to pull in the existing version linker script by adding to the target-specific LDFLAGS makefile variable:

```
$(LIB_PATH)/libsctp.so: LDFLAGS += \
    -Xlinker --version-script=$(MODULE_PATH)/src/lib/Versions.map
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the function [was moved in April 2009](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=cdd8930e6ae40e67bd5ac4a855122a7babc81226) from `libavformat/util.c` to a new file in `libavcodec/avpacket.c`. The [comment in internal.h](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/internal.h;h=46a05e124c46292d85ccfbbdbeddd50a8946f8f9;hb=refs/heads/master#l196) states explicitly:

> If a function is moved from one library to another, a wrapper must be retained in the original location to preserve binary compatibility.

But it is impossible to retain binary compatibility when a function is moved between libraries.

Note that this bug was reported in [Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47765) more than a year ago.

By the way, there is no need to edit `config.h` manually: you can run `./configure --disable-symver`.

Comment: Actually, in the version of FFmpeg I'm using in this revision (r25864 from December 2010), the `--disable-symver` option does not exist, so the manual edit is necessary.  I'm excited to hear about the configure option, though!  I'll use that when we switch to newer FFmpeg or Libav.

Answer (score 0):

It took someone else to point this out to me, so I thought I might as well put it on here so others like me can understand ognian's answer:

This translates to editing `config.h` after you run `./configure` and making the `SYMVER`-related entries are set to 0.  Like so:

```
#define HAVE_SYMVER 0
#define HAVE_SYMVER_GNU_ASM 0
#define HAVE_SYMVER_ASM_LABEL 0
```