# How to let ld use PIC version of libc.a

Tags: c, linker, ld, static-linking, libc

To link gcc statically into a shared library, based on the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344830/possible-to-build-a-shared-library-with-static-link-used-library), the remaining problem is how to let the linker use the PIC version of libc.a instead of the non-PIC version. The problem is the same as that answer:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -O0 -fexceptions -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
ld -shared -static -o test.so main.o -lc
ld: //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `tcache' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

This is what I'v tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libc-pic //then libc6-pic get installed successfully
ld -shared -static -o test.so main.o -lc //same as above, same error
ld -shared -static -o test.so main.o -lc-pic //not working: cannot find -lc-pic
ld -shared -static -o test.so main.o -lc6-pic //not working: cannot find -lc6-pic
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. I assure you, you will not get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the list of files in the package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libc6-pic/filelist) there is a `libc_pic.a` so the correct option seems to be `-lc_pic`.

Comment: There are new problem: ld: test.so: version node not found for symbol pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Bad value. Do you happen to know the answer too?

Comment: @jw_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816199/14215102 <- I think that's what the .map files in the file list are for?

Comment: @jw_, have you succeeded with this? Looks like the symbol versioning is broken for many functions, not just this one. Moreover, I even don't understand where pthread_cond_wait is coming from, because I don't have a dependency on it!